# what is the different with malloc_size and sizeof

Tags: objective-c, size, malloc, sizeof

I am using Ojb-c, and I want to know the memory size of an object, but I got this,

```
NSObject *obj = [[[NSObject alloc] init] autorelease];

NSLog(@"malloc size of myObject: %zd", malloc_size(obj));
NSLog(@"size of myObject: %zd", sizeof(obj));

  malloc size of myObject: 16
  size of myObject: 4
```

I know the sizeof(obj) is 4, because the pointer size on ios 32 is 4 bytes, what is the difference?

But more than this,

```
@interface TestObj : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *arr;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int count;

@end

@implementation TestObj

@end


    TestObj *obj2 = [[[TestObj alloc] init] autorelease];

    NSLog(@"malloc size of obj2: %zd", malloc_size(obj2));
    NSLog(@"size of obj2: %zd", sizeof(obj2));

  malloc size of obj2: 16
  size of obj2: 4
```

how could I know the real size of TestObj ? thanks.

Comment: Note that neither sizeof nor malloc_size will tell you the number of actual bytes used by an object.

Comment: You are right, I find that it's really hard to tell the actual bytes of an object after google.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sizeof` the object is how much space it requires for that object to be stored in memory. The `malloc_size` is how much space was actually allocated for it (for example, in a memory allocation system with fixed-size pools, you might be allocated a different amount depending on how much other memory was in use).

Comment: You mean the actual size of NSObject and TestObject both 16?

Comment: it depends what you mean by the "actual size". The OS has allocated 16 bytes for each of the two, if that's what you mean.

Comment: Thanks Vicky.     the "actual size" means the reals size of that object and it's property have.

Comment: I think I got this      NSObject *obj3 = nil;
    
    NSLog(@"malloc size of obj3: %zd", malloc_size(obj3));
    NSLog(@"size of obj3: %zd", sizeof(obj3));malloc size of obj3: 0   size of obj3: 4

Comment: You can't get the actual size of an object.  At all.

Comment: Right, but another time or on a different platform you might find sizeof obj2: 4 malloc_size obj2: 32.

Comment: @Vicky And both numbers would be wrong... take the malloc_size() of an NSMutableArray with 0, 100, and 100000 objects in it, for example.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof()` is a compile-time measurement. Note that `sizeof(obj)` in your example is telling you the size of the pointer variable, not the size of the object it points to. Note that the size of an Objective-C object is not known at compile time, so `sizeof` will not work for them.

`malloc_size()` is a runtime measurement. It tells you the size of a block allocated with `malloc`. Note that `malloc` often rounds up, so this size may be larger than necessary. Note that some objects are not allocated with `malloc` so `malloc_size()` will return zero.